# Remove standard run arguments in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, build, g++

I'm currently working with Netbeans 8.2, g++, QT 5.11 and a library called IBPP for database access on a FireBird server.
My main problem is, that IBPP programs can not build with a unicode character set. This is no problem when I build a normal C++ application, the standard build command is (copied from the console):

```
g++    -c -g -I../../IBPP -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
```

Now I want to use IBPP in a QT project, but the project automaticly builds with the following arguments:

```
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -Wall -W -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -Inbproject -I. -I../../IBPP/ -IC:/Qt/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/mingw53_32/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/mingw53_32/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/mingw53_32/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/mingw53_32/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/mingw53_32/include/QtCore -I. -I. -IC:/Qt/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/mingw53_32/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
```

As you can see, the build command has the arguments *-DUNICODE* and -D_UNICODE and I am guessing that these arguments are the reason for the build problems I currently experience.

How can I edit these standard build arguments, or how can I remove these specific two options from my run command? There is no option in the project settings menu.

UPDATE:

The code I want to test is very minimalistic, it just includes the library.

```
#define IBPP_WINDOWS = true
#define IBPP_GCC = true

#include <cstdlib>
#include "core/all_in_one.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

When I build this project as a normal "C++ Application" project, with the first run command, it works fine.

But when I build it as a "QT Application" project, with the second command, I get the following errors from the included library:

```
In file included from ../../IBPP/core/all_in_one.cpp:35:0,
                 from main.cpp:19:
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp: In member function 'ibpp_internals::GDS* ibpp_internals::GDS::Call()':
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:142:39: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'HINSTANCE__* LoadLibraryW(LPCWSTR)'
     mHandle = LoadLibrary(path.c_str());
                                       ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:162:58: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'DWORD GetModuleFileNameW(HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, DWORD)'
    int len = GetModuleFileName(NULL, fbdll, sizeof(fbdll));
                                                          ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:170:35: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'WCHAR* lstrcatW(LPWSTR, LPCWSTR)'
     lstrcat(fbdll, "\\fbembed.dll");// Local copy could be named fbembed.dll
                                   ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:171:32: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'HINSTANCE__* LoadLibraryW(LPCWSTR)'
     mHandle = LoadLibrary(fbdll);
                                ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:175:37: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'WCHAR* lstrcatW(LPWSTR, LPCWSTR)'
      lstrcat(fbdll, "\\fbclient.dll"); // Or possibly renamed fbclient.dll
                                     ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:176:33: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'HINSTANCE__* LoadLibraryW(LPCWSTR)'
      mHandle = LoadLibrary(fbdll);
                                 ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:186:30: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'LONG RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY, LPCWSTR, DWORD, REGSAM, PHKEY)'
     KEY_READ, &hkey_instances) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                              ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:192:15: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'LONG RegQueryValueExW(HKEY, LPCWSTR, LPDWORD, LPDWORD, LPBYTE, LPDWORD)'
        &buflen) == ERROR_SUCCESS && keytype == REG_SZ)
               ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:194:40: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'WCHAR* lstrcatW(LPWSTR, LPCWSTR)'
      lstrcat(fbdll, "bin\\fbclient.dll");
                                        ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:195:33: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'HINSTANCE__* LoadLibraryW(LPCWSTR)'
      mHandle = LoadLibrary(fbdll);
                                 ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:204:40: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'HINSTANCE__* LoadLibraryW(LPCWSTR)'
    mHandle = LoadLibrary("fbclient.dll");
                                        ^
../../IBPP/core/_ibpp.cpp:209:38: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'HINSTANCE__* LoadLibraryW(LPCWSTR)'
     mHandle = LoadLibrary("gds32.dll");
```

I have read that these errors could upcome with the unicode charset, so I am guessing that the errors result from the two flags in the second run command.

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: What exactly are _"the build problems I currently experience"_? Can you update your post with the details?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to Unicode use in Windows. In this case functions lstrcatW are automatically use instead od lstrcatA that are used as ANSI functions with char* arguments. A possible solution is to modify the source code to A functions, i.e. lstrcatA, LoadLibraryA etc.